# Run Out without bails

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

> A batsman is Run out if at any time while the ball is in play no
>   part of his bat or person is grounded behind the popping crease and
>   his **wicket(bails) is fairly put down** by the opposing side.
>                   - **[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_out)**

Consider the situation, if a batsman was bowled on a no-ball and the bails were down the stumps then the batsmen are running for a run, at this time, how the fielders will try to run out the batsmen?

Consider this situation,

Batsmen are running between the wickets after hitting the ball inside the ground, the ball was thrown to the fielder/WK, he(WK) then hit the stumps with the ball, all the three stumps were pulled off the ground, but the batsman got reached and the ball slipped from his hand and gone for overthrows, now the batsmen started running between the wickets, now how the fielders will try to run out the batsmen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it will be useful

> If the bails have already been removed, a fielder can remove a remaining stump by pulling it out or hit out the stump(ensure that the stump is fully out of ground) from the ground with the ball in their hands. A fielder can also "remake" the stumps and remove a stump/bail to effect a runout.

from the link [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dismissal_%28cricket%29#Law_38%3a_Run_out) and [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061124094133AANZJJA)

Answer (score 5):

No if the bails are already off the stumps then the fielder can pull the stump out from the ground and batsmen will be given out as a run out.

Adding to the answer by [Ashutosh Mishra](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/run-out-without-bails/2737#2737)

Bangladesh Wicket Keeper Mushfiqur Rahim had used this technique in the match against England in World Cup 2011 to Out England Matt Prior.(though it was Stump Out)

You can watch the image here on 
http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc_cricket_worldcup2011/content/image/505600.html

And video of the wicket in HighLights [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=md5rfFQeAeM)

Hope it helps.